# How to run multiple instances of virt-manager?

Tags: libvirt, virt-manager, xforwarding

I set up X-Forwarding from my SSH client on Windows with the goal to manage my virtual machines using the virt-manager GUI. I don't think there is a way to do so natively from Windows.

Now I noticed that I cannot open virt-manager on one side if it is already open on the other side. If it's already running on my server, I can't open it with X-Forwarding, and vice versa.

I don't think this kind of separation is actually necessary, it certainly isn't in my case where I'm the only user anyway. Is there a way to allow multiple instances to be running at the same time?

Comment: Not sure if it fits your definition of "natively", but virt-manager is included in [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), so you can install it directly on your Windows machine.